# How to let wordpress change e-mail and user name at same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Is there a way can let user change the username and email address as the same time when a user update his email address to a new one in wordpress profile cpanel?
   I want to user login his account as the email address as its username,but if someone change his email ,the login username will not as same as the new one,so the user can not login by the new email address,right?
   For example,a user's login name and email address was

login name(username):myname@hotmail.com

Email address:       myname@hotmail.com

After he change the new email,
   login name(username):myname@hotmail.com (I want the login name as newname@live.com)

Email address:       newname@live.com

So how to let the username automatically change as the emaill address when user update the email to a new one(in wordpress profile cpanel)?

I used below code to get the user id:

```
   $email_address='myname@hotmail.com';
   $the_user = get_user_by('email',$email_address);
   $user_id= $the_user->ID;
```

And I know change the user email address can use below codes,but I don't know where shall I put this to work when user update their email in cpnal,not in some my customize button:

```
$new_email_address='newname@live.com'
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'user_email' => $new_email_address));
```